# Delphi: TObjectList won't free object after Delete() is called

Tags: delphi, destructor, rad-studio, tlist, tobjectlist

I have a `TObjectList<TUSBDevice>`, where `TUSBDevice` is a class I've made. I tried calling `Delete` with the index passed as a parameter but that it simply does what `TList.Delete()` does: removes the pointer from the list but doesn't free the object itself.

The breakpoint I placed on `TUSBDevice.Destroy()` doesn't break when `Delete()` is called. I also had a watch on the `TObjectList` and I can see the item gets removed from the list but the contents at the memory address of the object don't get freed.

Destructor of `TUSBDevice`:

```
destructor TUSBDevice.Destroy();
begin
  removeDatabaseEntry();
  filteredFolders.Free();
  fileQueue.Free();
end;
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] Your question as-is does not have enough information to reproduce your issue.

Comment: You likely forgot to mark the `TUSBDevice` destructor declaration with `override`: `destructor Destroy; override;`. Or your object list doesn't own its members.

Comment: That was the problem Andreas, thanks. I always forget I need to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to answer your question since it doesn't contain a minimal reproducible example; the issues doesn't lie in the code you posted, but elsewhere.

Still, the most common cause of an "overridden" destructor not running is that it is in fact not overridden. So I can almost bet that your `Destroy` declaration is missing the `override`:

```
TUSBDevice = class
  // ...
public
  // ...
  destructor Destroy; override;
  // ...
end;
```

Comment: Would it be a good idea to make my constructor overidden as well?

Comment: That depends on several factors. A class can have several constructors, and the `TObject` constructor isn't virtual so it *cannot* be overridden. So, if the base class is `TObject`, you have nothing to override. On the other hand, if the base class is `TDevice` and that one has a virtual constructor that must run in order for the object to be properly initialized and your new constructor has the same argument list, then it is a good idea. And of course, don't forget to call the `inherited` constructor (and the inherited destructor, at least if it isn't `TObject.Destroy` which is empty).

Comment: Typically, an overridden constructor *starts with* `inherited;` and an overridden destructor *ends with* `inherited;`.

Comment: Yeah, the base class of `TUSBDevice` is `TObject`. Thank you, that makes sense.

Comment: Always include the call to the inherited constructor and destructor. That way your code doesn't break surprisingly if you ever choose to change the parent class.

Comment: I agree with @DavidHeffernan. Always calling the inherited constructor or destructor is best practice.

Answer (score -1):

Immediately after creating a TObjectList member, you must change his property OwnsObjects to True. This allows the destruction of the objects linked to the Object List when no more is necessary. (i.e., when you delete a member or when you free the TObjectList member)

```
Pieces := TObjectList<TPiece>.Create;
Pieces.OwnsObjects := True;
```

Comment: _you must change his property OwnsObjects to True_ - no, it is [redundant](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/CodeExamples/Alexandria/en/Generics_Collections_TObjectList_(Delphi)): _The OwnsObjects property is set by default to true_.